# oracle 11g apex not accessible

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5

I have come through a situation where two process on my system were configured on 8080. I had oracle 11g installed and it was working fine. Then I installed jenkins and when I tried to reach localhost:8080/apex... it defaulted to jenkins. So I forced kil the process listning at 8080 and changed the port for jenkins. The problem is that I am unable to reach the oracle 11g apex page.It is saying connection refused. I have checked this

in sql plus:

SELECT dbms_xdb.gethttpport FROM dual;

8080

my lsnrctl status is running. can any one please help me how to start the db now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dammit I just started TNSLSR and it is working all good now